# Alamofire with YouTube API Issues (Swift 3)

Tags: swift, youtube-api, alamofire

I'm having some trouble converting my old Alamofire code to the new Swift 3 version. I'm getting the error: *Extra argument 'method' in call*

```
//        Fetch the videos dynamiclly through the YouTube Data API

   Alamofire.request("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems", method: .get, parameters: ["part":"snippet", "playlistId":UPLOADS_PLAYLIST_ID,"key":API_KEY], encoding: ParameterEncoding.URL, headers: nil)
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in the *method* argument but in the encoding which you can set to `URLEncoding.default` also since the header is nil then i guess you dont need it

```
let parameters: Parameters = ["part":"snippet",
                                "playlistId":UPLOADS_PLAYLIST_ID,
                                "key":API_KEY]
let url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems"

Alamofire.request(url,
                  method: .get,
                  parameters: parameters,
                  encoding: URLEncoding.default)
   .responseData(completionHandler: { response in
    //do what you want
})
```

by the way you can change `responseData` back to what you already have